# Role of Table LocalizationResourceByScreen in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to understand the database model for localization/multi language support in Acumatica.

I got most of it but I still don't fully understand the role of the table "LocalizationResourceByScreen"

My guess was : the table is referencing the "localization resources" that are actually used and displayed on a screen (one resource can be shared on several screens), others are not used nor displayed?

anyone can confirm on this?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the LocalizationResourceByScreen table is to link records from the LocalizationValue table with particular screens in Acumatica, on which those values are displayed. To be more specific, records from LocalizationResourceByScreen are shown in the **Usage Details** details popup, which appears when the user clicks on either of 4 **View Usage Details** buttons on the **Translation Dictionaries** screen.

For example, let's explore on what screens ***Extra Usage Price*** is used:

- if you open Usage Details popup from the Default Values grid, there will be 4 records listed in the popup. Also notice ***Extra Usage Price*** used in 2 DACs: `PX.Objects.CT.ContractDetail` and `PX.Objects.CT.ContractItem`:
  [image]
- if now you open Usage Details popup from the Key-Specific Values grid for the `PX.Objects.CT.ContractDetail`, there will be only 2 records listed in the popup:
  [image]
- and if now you open Usage Details popup from the Key-Specific Values grid for the `PX.Objects.CT.ContractItem`, there will be only also only 2 of 4 records listed in the popup:
  [image]

Comment: Well thanks for the detailed answer, that was appreciated!

 So if I get it right when collecting the strings from the translastion Dictionnaries page it collects only the one used on the screen right, or you can have key specific Values with no view usage? I was wondering if I had to worry about fields that are not used in any screens so far.

Comment: You can have key specific Values with no view usage.